# PHP - preg_match for end of filename containing variable numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Regular expressions are a bit of a challenge for me. My goal is to determine whether or not a filename ends with this:

`_100x200.jpg`

where `100` and `200` could be any integer of any number of digits.

So what I'm looking for is a way to match these filenames:

- `photo_1x3.jpg`
- `abc_100x100.jpg`
- `a file name_50x2000.jpg`

Could anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/_\d+x\d+\.jpg$/i
```

Using inside your code you can do:

```
if (preg_match('/_\d+x\d+\.jpg$/', $image, $arr)) {
     // matched
     var_dump($arr);   
}
```

Comment: Wow, I thought that `\d` would only match one digit. Easier than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: `\d` is short cut for `[0-9]` and `\d+` will match 1 or more digits.

Comment: @MMiller: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you have to wait 6 minutes for reasons I don't quite understand....

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to both check and get your dimensions:

```
<?php

$str = array(
  'photo_1x3.jpg',
  'abc_100x100.jpg',
  'a file name_50x2000.jpg'
 );

foreach($str as $s) {
  $match = preg_match( '/_([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/', $s, $matches);

  echo $match ? 'exists' : 'doesn\'t exist';

  print_r($matches);
 }

?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/65623